# Ubuntu server 11.10 - create nameservers

Tags: linux, ubuntu, domain-name-system, nameserver, domains

i don't know much about this, so i will need you to give directions in order to better understand whole this thing.
I have dedicated server, which i configured to use as web server. When i type in my browser http://ip adress, content opens, so everything is ok.

from other side, i registered 5 domains on godaddy and i want to point that domains to my server. But, that's the problem, i don't know how. When it comes to set up nameservers for domains on godaddy, i just don't know what to type and what to configure on my server.

Can anybody give me directions what should i install on my server and configure? But to be more specific, because, as i mentioned, i don't know much about this.

My server is running Ubuntu server 11.10. I have installed DNS server, bind9 and dnsutils but NOTHING configured.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access your server with a name like `www.yourdomain.com`, you just need to login to your godaddy account and edit the zone file of `yourdomain.com` and create a new record A or CNAME (for www) to point to your public ip. That's it.

If godaddy is providing the DNS service for you, you don't need to run your own DNS server to be accessible from the Internet.

Of course, you need to define your DNS records with public IPs and make sure the needed ports are opened.

Comment: Thank you. I will go and edit zone. But, how can i define my DNS records with public Ips and make sure that needed ports are opened?

Comment: and what should i enter in Ns1 and Ns2 on go daddy? My server's ip or leave them blank when i edit zone?